# Problem when compiling presentation

Tags: beamer

Preparing my presentation, everything was going well until one time when compiling I got the following error:

```
(beamer.cls
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasercs.sty")
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \beamer@rcsdate \space \beamer@version 
                                                  \space A class for typeset...
l.14 ...ace A class for typesetting presentations]

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

I don't understand what this means. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a problem due to a faulty installation of MiKTeX. You should avoid using file names with spaces anyway.

Comment: Dear egreg,  the same problem persists, nothing new

Answer (score 3):

Your log shows

```
(beamer.cls
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasercs.sty")
```

That is, you have a beamer.cls in the current folder but are then including beamer internals from the main miktex input tree. the file in the current folder almost certainly should not be there, then miktex would show

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamer.cls"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasercs.sty")
```

What is supposed to happen is that `beamerbasercs.sty` is input which on line 13 has

```
\def\beamer@version{3.36}
```

which defines `\beamer@version` however you are showing this command as undefined.

Comment: So what is supposed to do to solve the problem ?????

Comment: @user96111 as I said: first remove the local file `beamer.cls` in your document folder. Since that file is most likely the problem and only you have access to that file, hard to say more.